# Glucose and related aldohexoses are interconvertible with a little base. Does anybody know how much of each sugar is present at equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium, carbohydrates

If you add **NaOH to D-glucose** in water, a mixture of almost **all aldohexoses** will arise over time, including **mannose** and **fructose**. I wonder how much of each will be present and what could explain the distribution. My assumption is that the amount will match stability and that the most stable D-beta-glucose will be most abundant. I'd love to see better quantitative data on this. Do you know how much of each aldohexose is produced?

I found a paper using sodium titanate nanotubes as catalyst but not sodium hydroxide. There, Kumar et al. show in [figure 3a](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Kinetics-of-glucose-isomerization-at-different-temperature-conditions-a-60-C-b-80_fig3_327218619)(CC-by) that glucose is converted to mostly fructose (blue) and to a lesser extent mannose (red).

[image: CC Kumar et al. 2018]

The paper does not really answer my question as it only touches upon 2 aldohexoses and doesn't give a molar % (or I didn't find it). I do wonder how much of each sugar would be present in the basic reaction of glucose described above. Does anybody know of experiments to answer that?

Comment: Maybe look at this: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11559169/

Comment: Thanks, Buck, for the link to the paper by Zhu et al. It's an interesting NMR study, teasing apart how much of which acyclic and cyclic form of various aldohexoses including glucose is present. It does not look at the interconversion of those. That's what peaked my interest; the fact the glucose can be converted to the other aldohexoses.